# Mysql SELECT that returns only the most recent and next most recent row where a column matches, within a time constraint

Tags: mysql, date

UPDATE:  Kordirko's solution below does work in SQL Fiddle, but as mentioned in my comments the code does not work in my own mysql db.  I have copied the schema commands directly and run a copy of the query from fiddle.  I checked both and they are identical code.  I verified same 5.1.61 mysql version between my db and fiddle.  In the live db, 3 rows are returned for id 2 and on fiddle only 2 rows are returned (desired effect).  Could fiddle be altering the query before passing it through?

**Background:**

I have a table of data that is being kept as a history of scan results.  Typically it is used to plot trends of the results over time, but I would like to try something else.  I want to provide the most recent trend upwards or down (as a percentage) if there are at least 2 data points.  More specifically, I would like to also constrain this to the most recent 7 days to limit the scope of the trends to the active projects.

Note the table is only updated on the first time a project is run and also if the issues_count has changed from a previous run.

**Sample Table:**

```
id  issues_count  updated
1   7922          2013-10-02 08:22:31
1   7981          2013-10-03 08:22:43
2   7754          2013-10-10 12:06:45
2   7922          2013-10-11 12:06:45
2   7981          2013-10-12 02:09:43
3   15536         2013-10-12 02:09:43
4   1233          2013-10-11 12:06:45
4   2493          2013-10-12 02:09:43
5   4349          2013-10-12 02:09:44
```

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `issue_history` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `issues_count` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  KEY `id_index` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii;
```

**Results logic:**

In the above sample, I want to ignore both '1' id entries because they are older than 7 days (from today).  I want to not return anything for id '3' and id '5' as they only have one data point so far.  For ids '2' and '4' I want to return the most recent and the one directly preceeding it based on timestamp (not any prior to that, 2 max).

**Example results:**

```
2   7922          2013-10-11 12:06:45
2   7981          2013-10-12 02:09:43
4   1233          2013-10-11 12:06:45
4   2493          2013-10-12 02:09:43
```

**Other thoughts:**

Order isn't that important, although I would likely want to group them first by id (asc or desc) and then by the timestamp in desc.

If I were going to make an inefficient attempt, I could handle this by doing a select on all ids in the last 24 hours, then maybe select all rows that match those ids, order by the timestamp desc, limit 2.  Then my code would have to remove results with less than 2 rows per id.  Likely I would pursue making a subquery select out of the first and embedding into the second.  I still think this is not the best approach, but should function.

My concern is this table can grow at the rate of a couple thousand rows a day and I would like to try to take the least amount of time possible for the command to be run.  I especially don't want to hit the db twice from the program.

Comment: Can you post your table structure and an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Sébastien - I changed the sample data heading to sample table and included the table structure.  I have not tried anything yet, although I was heading down the road I mentioned... but I don't want to spend a lot of time if it's very inefficient.  I figured there might be a way using joins instead, but they aren't my strength.  Currently I am just plotting all the data per id, so this is something new.

Comment: Bad first post to stack overflow.  I am not showing my attempt, but the problem is my attempt would involve code outside of mysql and I would suspect it can be done in mysql.  I will be happy to post some attempts tonight if people want to hold off on commenting.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT id,
       issues_count,
       updated
FROM (
  SELECT sub1.*,
         IF(@last_id=sub1.id,(@rn:=@rn+1),(@rn:=1)) rn,
         (@last_id:=sub1.id) last_id
  FROM (
     SELECT ih.* 
     FROM issue_history ih
     JOIN (
       SELECT id
       FROM issue_history
        -- the most recent 7 days 
        WHERE updated > now() - interval 7 day
        GROUP BY id
        -- if there are at least 2 data points
        HAVING count(*) >= 2
     ) ih1
     ON ih.id = ih1.id AND ih.updated > now() - interval 7 day
     CROSS JOIN ( SELECT (@rn:=0),(@last_id=-12345)) init_variables
  ) sub1
  --  by id (asc or desc) and then by the timestamp in desc
  ORDER BY sub1.id ASC, sub1.updated DESC
) subquery
-- not any prior to that, 2 max
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY id ASC, updated ASC
```

Demo ---> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4309b/30

------- EDIT ------------

Another version that determines the most recent date of the pair and sorts records by this date

```
SELECT id,
       issues_count,
       updated,
       most_recent_date
FROM (
  SELECT sub1.*,
         IF(@last_id=sub1.id,(@rn:=@rn+1),(@rn:=1)) rn,
         (@last_id:=sub1.id) last_id
  FROM (
     SELECT ih.*, ih1.most_recent_date
     FROM issue_history ih
     JOIN (
       -- max( updated ) --> most recent date
       SELECT id, max( updated ) most_recent_date
       FROM issue_history
        -- the most recent 7 days 
        WHERE updated > now() - interval 7 day
        GROUP BY id
        -- if there are at least 2 data points
        HAVING count(*) >= 2
     ) ih1
     ON ih.id = ih1.id AND ih.updated > now() - interval 7 day
     CROSS JOIN ( SELECT (@rn:=0),(@last_id=-12345)) init_variables
  ) sub1
  --  by id (asc or desc) and then by the timestamp in desc
  ORDER BY sub1.id ASC, sub1.updated DESC
) subquery
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY most_recent_date, id, updated
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1eb9fe/1

Comment: Holy cow.  Having not really dealt with SQL much for the last 12+ years and only recently doing basic stuff... I obviously need to crack open a book and spend some time boning up.  Thanks for the in-line comments as well.  I didn't think about using 'having count' to pick out ids with a min data point, despite it being obvious.  In fact, a lot of it is obvious when I read it, but I never would have come up with it on my own.

Comment: BTW, i'll go build up some points with the perl questions and rep you.     If you saw the mess I had going, I just got the stuff finished to simply obtain the latest record by date for each id.  Thanks again sir.

Comment: After joining with the other table I needed info from and looking at all the data, I realized my original assumption was incorrect.  It seems I really needed the results to be sorted by the most recent updated value per pair, but keeping the same ids returned in adjacent rows.  Is this even possible?  I have already worked around it in post-processing via the receiving code, but I was curious.

Comment: @easyperl, I edit the answer and apped another version of the query, best regards.

Comment: I haven't tried the new one yet as the code on my side already handles the other.  Task for another day this week.  But, I do have an issue.  Example of my join addition is at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/e7119/1/0 and this works.  Same sample table/data imported into my mysql, with the same query run... I get 3 rows for id 2 in the results, which I only get 2 on sqlfiddle.  Same mysql 5.1.61 versions.  I am getting the extra rows on my live data as well, which is breaking the scripting end that expects 2 per id.  Ideas on why the discrepancy?

Comment: I should mention that your original sqlfiddle schema and query, imported into the db, has the same 3 row return for id 2 instead of 2 rows.